# Why is php-fpm getting the wrong client ip address?

Tags: php-fpm

Good day!

I have two docker containers `php-fpm` and `nginx` I need to get the real ip address of the client, but instead of 127.0.0.1 (localhost) I get 172.0.0.1 what could be the problem?

Below I have indicated the configuration that I am using, as well as a picture so that you could understand me better.

[how i see interaction. Smile-client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Teu.png)

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./nginx/conf/hosts:/etc/hosts

            - ./app:/var/www/app
        networks:
            - app_network

    php-fpm:
        build: ./phpfpm
        depends_on:
            - nginx
        volumes:
            - ./phpfpm/conf/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
            - ./phpfpm/conf/hosts:/etc/hosts

            - ./app:/var/www/app
        networks:
            - app_network
    
networks:
    app_network:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: "172.0.0.0/24"
                - subnet: "2001:3984:3989::/64"
```

as you can see I have merged host port 80 with container port 80
so I expect the correct ip to be passed. What am I doing wrong? I would be grateful for any answer, thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please post your nginx config.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for are [martian packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_packet). A sane kernel won't let you do this. The loopback is virtual and strictly local.

You should be able though to pass your other IP address to the subnet when you access the mapped port at that IP.